# CollectionEntry is any?

Tags: astrojs

I have Content Collections enabled and I have the following `/content/config.ts`:

```
import { z, defineCollection } from "astro:content";

const articlesCollection = defineCollection({
    schema: z.object({
      title: z.string(),
      description: z.string(),
      tags: z.array(z.string()).optional()
    })
});

const postsCollection = defineCollection({
  schema: z.object({
    title: z.string(),
    description: z.string().optional(),
    tags: z.array(z.string()).optional(),
    publishDate: z.date()
  })
});

export const collections = {
    'articles': articlesCollection,
    'posts': postsCollection
};
```

I want to retrieve a type of articles' frontmatter. In my layout, I have the following fence:

```
---
import type { CollectionEntry } from 'astro:content';

interface Props {
    slug: string;
    frontmatter: CollectionEntry<'articles'>['data']; // any?
}

const { frontmatter, slug } = Astro.props;
---
```

It seems that `CollectionEntry<'articles'>['data']` resolves to `any`. Why is that?

Comment: It may be possible that content collection types have not been generated yet? Have you run `astro sync` or `astro dev` in this project? Do you have any files in `src/content/articles/`?

Comment: Yes, I did all of those

Comment: You may have hit a bug. I’d recommend opening a bug report on GitHub if possible: https://github.com/withastro/astro/issues/new/choose

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Have you resolved it somehow or created any bug report?

Comment: I found the issue for my case. Instead of exporting `collections` from config.ts I was exporting `collection` (missing s) so in generated `types.d.ts`, `type ContentConfig` was set to `never` instead of `typeof import("../src/content/config")`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `config.ts` in to root `src/content`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8teU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD6Z5.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).